# RPi4 Serial port not working on either Raspberry OS or Ubuntu

Tags: raspbian, serial, ubuntu

I've been struggling to get my RPi4 serial working over pins 8,10.

I have both a Raspberry OS image and an Ubuntu 18.04 image for the RPi4.  In either case, when I use RASPI-CONFIG to disable console and enable uart, I'm still unable to use minicom to see characters or to receive data over serial.

```
dmesg | grep tty
console [tty1] enabled
serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO is a PL011 rev2 
serial: ttySo at MMIO is a 16550
```

```
ls -l /dev/serial*
/dev/serial0 -> ttyS0
/dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0
```

```
setserial -g /dev/tty*
/dev/ttyAMA0, UART undefined, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 19
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550, Port 0x0000, IRQ: 21
```

```
sudo minicom -o -D /dev/serial0 or 1
no characters reflected back with loopback in place
```

enable_uart=1 is in config.txt

I'm getting the exact same results on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Raspberry OS.  Neither enables the serial port to work.  What else could I try or am I missing?

Comment: If you loop TX with RX on the same device you can see the char that you send is also received on the same device. This is a common trouble shooting pratice for serial devices.

Comment: What are you actually trying to connect to via serial?

Comment: Using a loopback wire for the test.  Ultimately connecting to Roboclaw motor driver via serial.  It does not indicate it needs a level shifter but I'm now wondering if my past experimentation with the connection to the Roboclaw put 5v on Rx somwhow.

Answer (score 7):

Here's some things I needed to do specifically to connect to a device like the Roboclaw. I got this to work on Ubuntu20.04, Ubuntu18.04 and raspberry pi OS (raspbian)

- add `enable_uart=1` to `/boot/config.txt`
- remove `console=serial0,115200` from `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` on Ubuntu and `/boot/cmdline.txt` on Raspberry Pi OS
- disable the serial console: `sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service && sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service`
- make sure you have `pyserial` installed if you're using the python serial library, not `python-serial` from `apt`.
- create the following udev file:

```
KERNEL=="ttyS0", SYMLINK+="serial0" GROUP="tty" MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="ttyAMA0", SYMLINK+="serial1" GROUP="tty" MODE="0660"
```

and reload your udev rules: `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger`

- change the group of the new serial devices

```
sudo chgrp -h tty /dev/serial0
sudo chgrp -h tty /dev/serial1
```

- The devices are now under the tty group. Need to add the user to the tty group and dialout group:

```
sudo adduser $USER tty
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

- update the permissions for group read on the devices

```
sudo chmod g+r /dev/ttyS0
sudo chmod g+r /dev/ttyAMA0
```

- reboot

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. I had issues with the serial port probably conflicting with BT on RPi Zero 2W and RPi 3 A+ with Ubuntu Server 20.04. Now it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix UARTs of raspberry by using another UARTs of raspberry pi 4 because rpi4 has 6 UARTs port .

Example :

- UART0 , UART1 , UART2 , UART3 , UART4 , UART5

My Devices :

- RPI : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (MASTER)
- OS : Ubuntu Mate 20.04
- SLAVE : Teensy 4.1 (Communicate with raspberry pi 4)

References

- [Raspberry Pi Pinout](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/uart)
- [Raspberry Pi UARTs Configuration](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104464/where-are-%20the-uarts-on-the-raspberry-pi-4)

You can enable UARTs on RPi4 by editing files /boot/firmware/config.txt and add

```
dtoverlay=uartx
```

x is the number of your UARTs

or

Use can use my python script to enable UARTs and testing serial communication

- https://github.com/NonStopBle/PiAttachSerial

Question (What is path of UARTs):

- /dev/ttyACM0 - /dev/ttyACM5